# How does the Mockk library mock a non-interface class?

Tags: kotlin, mocking, mockk

When I built a structure like the one below, I saw that the classes that are not executed through the `interface`can also be mockable.
How does this work? Could it be related to `Kotlin`?

In fact, my question here is; How does it crush the function of a class without `override`? I'm curious about the background of this.

```
class Sample {
    fun returnFive() = 5
}

@Test
fun test(){
    var sample = Sample()
    sample = mockk {
        every { returnFive() } returns 10
    }
    assertEquals(5,sample.returnFive())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be rewritten as

```kotlin
class Sample {
    fun returnFive() = 5
}

@Test
fun test() {
    val sample: Sample = mockk()

    every { sample.returnFive() } returns 10

    assertEquals(10, sample.returnFive()) 
}
```

This allows us to see that `sample` becomes an instance of `Sample`, but `Mockk` is creating it, not you.

When you delegate this creation to `Mockk`, it does some magic to **replace that instance** with an instrumented one, which you can define extra behaviours. Mockk's author explained a little bit more about this in [this blog post](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/mocking-is-not-rocket-science-basics-ae55d0aadf2b) if you're interested.

---

> Could it be related to Kotlin?

This isn't exactly Kotlin's behaviour.

You could do the same thing when using Java with Mockito, for example.

Comment: In fact, my question here is; How does it crush the function of a class without "override"? I'm curious about the background of this.

Comment: It uses bytecode manipulation. I believe everything is done through ByteBuddy, but at a very high level: 1 - "subclass" your class. 2-make all the methods from your class delegate to mockk's class 3-let the program execute them as if it was your class